# Node.js - HTTP POST request issue in Postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server, postman

I was copying this code from a YouTube video about how to make a rest API with Node.js. The `GET` request and other stuff were working just fine until I tried a `POST` request then I encountered an error:

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:3000/posts.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

and I checked the console and this is what it showed

```
POST http://localhost:3000/posts
Error: socket hang up
Warning: This request did not get sent completely and might not have all the required system headers
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.24.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: ee8e3956-6963-45a5-8c7e-3bd41628b210
Host: localhost:3000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Request Body
```

The person in the video worked for him just fine so I am thinking maybe it has something to do with new updates since the video is a bit old. My version of Postman is 7.21.2

I would appreciate if anyone can help fix this issue as I have looked online for various answers and I can't find one specific to my own

Below is the app.js where I have set the port and router

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

require("dotenv/config");

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Import Routes
const postsRoute = require("./routes/posts");

//Middlewares
app.use("/posts", postsRoute);

//Routes
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("we are on home");
});

//Connect to DB
mongoose.connect(
    process.env.DB_CONNECT,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
    () => console.log("connected to DB!")
);

app.listen(3000);
```

and here is the code for post.js route

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Post = require("../models/Post");

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("we are on posts");
});

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
    });

    try {
        const savedPost = await post.save();
        res.json(savedPost);
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Rather than linking to pictures, could you copy the error messages from postman and the console and paste them into your question? Just the text is fine.

Comment: @quicklikerabbit I have edited the question and posted the error messages as suggested

Comment: Can you also post your code? It seems that your server isn't started on that port (3000).

Comment: I have added the code @TsvetanGanev